# H3C MSR20 40 Firmware

Tags: networking, firmware

Anyone have the firmware of H3C MSR20-40 router, i just lost it and cannot boot it now, just stuck in extended boot mode

I did try to download the firmware via the official web but its fail, because the file is locked, gladly if someone can send me the file